# Can I clear the application data while updating?

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

I am building a new version of my hybrid mobile app using sencha touch, corodva. In this new version, some of the features are removed . I want to clear the whole application data automatically while the user is updating the app.

Any Cordova API would help in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can't do this *while* you're updating the app (since that's under OS control), but upon startup, check for the presence of old data structures, and if they exist, delete your files. *How* you stored your files will determine how to get rid of them. For example, if you just stored into `localStorage`, you can erase it with `localStorage.clear()`.